# For which values of $a \in \Bbb{R}$ the limit $ \lim_\limits{n \to \infty} \big(1+\frac{n^2+1}{n^a}\big)$ is finite?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits

I want to know for which values of a $\in R$  this limit is finite:

$$     \lim_{n \to \infty} \bigg(1+\frac{n^2+1}{n^a}\bigg)$$

I think it is  $\forall a >2$ but my book says $$a \ge 3$$

Comment: You are correct. It is even $\forall a \geq 2$

Comment: I believe there is a misprint in the book. The answer is $a \geq 3$ for the limit of $(1+\frac {n^{2}+1)} {n^{a})^{n}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have $a_n =  1+\frac{n^2+1}{n^a} = \frac{n^a + n^2 + 1}{n^a}$.

If $a\lt2$ then $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = \infty$

If $a = 2$ then $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = 2$

If $a\gt2$ then $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = 1$

So it has finite limit when $a\ge2$.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the answer is $a\geqslant2$. In fact,$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{n^2+1}{n^2}\right)=2,$$whereas$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{n^2+1}{n^a}\right)=1$$if $a>2$. Furthermore, if $a<2$, then$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{n^2+1}{n^a}\right)=\infty.$$

Answer (score 0):

You obviously have a problem only with $\frac{n^2}{n^a}$ term. If you rewrite $a$ as $2+\epsilon$, with $\epsilon>0$ you get $n^{-\epsilon}$ which converged to 0, with $\epsilon=0$ you get 1, with $\epsilon<0$ your term diverges because $n^{\epsilon}$ tends to infinity